# Regex to replace path

Tags: css, regex

I have the below css

```
div style="background: transparent url('http://test.com/assets/admin/R7AcNoiUzbrr89.png') no-repeat"></div>

div style="background: transparent url(http://another.com/assets/admin/R7AcNeer89.png) no-repeat"></div>
```

How can I get rid of the hostname with a regex?

Thanks

Comment: Is this from an IDE or script? Let us know the technology you are using.

Comment: Which language are you using for replacing the value ? Python ? Java ? Php ?

Comment: script. javascript or python. anything you like

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace that :

```
style="(.*)(http://([^/])*)(.*)"
```

by that :

```
style="$1$4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
str.gsub(/http:\/\/[^\/]+([^\)])/i, '/')
```

Js:

```
str.replace(/http:\/\/[^\/]+([^\)])/i, '/')
```

Comment: Hi. Ideally it should contain the url( in the regex, as I do not want to replace any other elements (images etc)